# php - preg_replace a character not followed by a specific character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
this &foo and&foo but not &#bar haius&#bar
```

All "&foo" should be replaced by "&amp;foo" and "&#bar" should be left untouched. I.e. any & not followed by a # should be replaced. Any ideas?

I've tried the following but it's not going very well...

```
preg_replace('/&*$[#]*$/', '&amp;', "this &foo and&foo but not &#bar haius&#bar");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `'/&(?!#)/','&amp;'` would do it.

Comment: Maybe it should also be mentioned that it's called [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Genius, just genius - thank you! 14 seconds for an answer has got to be pretty close to a record?!

Comment: @Wrikken already gave the solution and joachim-isaksson gave the useful negative lookahead advice, and since I'm relatively new to SO, should I still mark r3mus's actual answer as correct etc?

Comment: "a character not followed by a specific character" must be the second most regex question just after "a character followed by a specific character". It's worth searching before asking since this has been answered a gazillion times already.

Comment: @svoop I appreciate the feedback but I did look on the web and on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=a+character+not+followed+by+a+specific+character) but I didn't find anything, hence the new question (perhaps my wording was wrong but I searched for the wording you used)

Comment: This looks like you're trying to convert ampersands to their proper HTML entities.  In that case, I think you'll also want to make sure you don't convert `&amp;` to `&amp&amp;`.

Comment: @hobailey: yeah, just mark r3mus answer as correct / accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to accomplish this, I added `amp` to this so you do not add an extra `&amp;` in front of an already existing occurrence.

```
$text = preg_replace('/&(?!#|amp)/', '&amp;', $text);
```

Regular expression:

```
&              '&'
(?!            look ahead to see if there is not:
  #            '#'
 |             OR
  amp          'amp'
)              end of look-ahead
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/76675)

If you are just trying to replace a small amount of specific strings, use `str_replace` or `strtr`

```
strtr($text, array('&foo' => '&amp;foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `/&(?!#)/` will do this (the negative lookahead).

`preg_replace('/&(?!#)/', '&amp;', "this &foo and&foo but not &#bar haius&#bar");`

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/cB1tW2